# easy calculation of weeks of certain period with java

Tags: java

Is there any easy library or approach to get the week (from which date ~ date) of certain periods?

Example:
There is `6 weeks(variable)` (start from 1 July, 2012 ~ 11 Aug, 2012).

I want to cut off the 6 weeks into `2 portions (variable)`. So the results will be

```
1) 1 July,2012 ~ 21 July, 2012

2) 22 July,2012 ~ 11 Aug, 2012... etc
```

With jodatime, I can easily get the number of weeks between certain periods though.

All I know is `Start Date and End Date` which both are variables and `cutoffweeks amount`(eg.6 weeks or 4 weeks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final LocalDate start = new LocalDate();
final LocalDate end3 = start.plusWeeks(3)
```

Its not exactly clear what you want, but [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) makes most things rather easy.

I guess you need something like :

```
public void doStruff(int cutOff){
  int portion = cutoff/2;
  final LocalDate start = new LocalDate();
  final LocalDate end = start.plusWeeks(portion)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an idea from your answer how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
    public class DateDiff {  
       public static void main(String[] args) {  
         String s1 = "06/01/2012";
         String s2 = "06/24/2012";
          DateDiff dd = new DateDiff();  
          Date then = null, now = null;  
          DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();  
          df.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getDefault() );  

             try {  
                then = df.parse( s1 + " 12:00 PM" );  
                now = df.parse( s2 + " 12:00 PM" );  
             } catch ( ParseException e ) {  
                System.out.println("Couldn't parse date: " + e );  
                System.exit(1);  
             } 
          long diff = dd.getDateDiff( now, then, Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR );  
          System.out.println("No of weeks: " + diff );  
       }  

       long getDateDiff( Date d1, Date d2, int calUnit ) {  
          if( d1.after(d2) ) {    // make sure d1 < d2, else swap them  
             Date temp = d1;  
             d1 = d2;  
             d2 = temp;  
          }  
          GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();  
          c1.setTime(d1);  
          GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();  
          c2.setTime(d2);  
          for( long i=1; ; i++ ) {           
             c1.add( calUnit, 1 );   // add one day, week, year, etc.  
             if( c1.after(c2) )  
                return i-1;  
          }  
       }  
    }
```